# iCloud updates only on app launch

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an iOS and OSX app that use core data and I'm trying to sync them using iCloud.

My problem is that when I update something in the OSX app, the iOS app will only show the update after a restart. I'm testing on a device, iOS 8.3, iCloud drive is enabled.

To investigate the issue, I added observers to the iOS app for the relevant notifications, including NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification. This is only called on the sync that happens when I launch the app.

I also set debugging levels:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
-com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel 3
```

Looking at the output, the update from the OSX app always arrives - but that's it. No notifications and when I fetch data the update is not there. It will be there only after the next time I launch the app.

I investigated a bit further, there's a folder in the device .../AppData/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/

which seems to contain the iCloud files, in store/ there's a myappname.sqlite file in which I think the app stores the current iCloud data. So after the logging of the updates finished, I downloaded this file, opened with sqlite and checked if the tables are updated and they aren't. So it fails even before writing to the iCloud sqlite store?

This is the log I see in the console, I don't see errors or warnings:

```
2015-05-30 13:18:50.001 test[785:252698] -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:](278): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityFilePresenter: 0x1742a16e0>
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a1680>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore
localPeerID: mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B

Got change notification for url: file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/.25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt.icloud
2015-05-30 13:18:50.001 test[785:252699] -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:](278): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityFilePresenter: 0x1742a16e0>
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a1680>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore
localPeerID: mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B

Got change notification for url: file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/.1D8977DB-5003-4890-BB1A-BD1A5585AD4C.1.cdt.icloud
2015-05-30 13:18:50.002 test[785:252700] -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs](316): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityFilePresenter: 0x1742a16e0>
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a1680>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore
localPeerID: mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B

Processing pending urls: (
"file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/.25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt.icloud"
)
2015-05-30 13:18:50.003 test[785:252700] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootLocation:](1102): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Changing path component to remove promise suffix previous: .25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt.icloud
2015-05-30 13:18:50.003 test[785:252700] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootLocation:](1104): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Changing path component to remove promise suffix new: .25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt
2015-05-30 13:18:50.003 test[785:252700] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootLocation:](1142): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Ignoring private file: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/.25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt.icloud
2015-05-30 13:18:50.003 test[785:252700] -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs](338): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Didn't get a location back for url: file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/.25742215-F540-4D6C-97B0-40839DA02C08.1.cdt.icloud
2015-05-30 13:18:50.008 test[785:252700] -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs](472): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityFilePresenter: 0x1742a16e0>
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a1680>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore
localPeerID: mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B

Status: {
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9f00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/87885B51-6E5C-4ADD-8903-18183FB55E5E.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262340> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9cc0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/baseline.meta" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1702683c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa5c0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/742F2C0E-2199-4521-8408-8D0DC5D53E26.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262640> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa0e0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/baseline.zip" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17006d600> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:4";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9d20>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/4219C00A-B39D-4043-A7DF-1C6E84A031B4.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262b00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9e40>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/F2D2F34E-3902-4127-B7A9-E85F0B159B0C.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174260e80> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a5ac0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/630D0759-73F5-4739-8FE1-ED061219A5AE.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170471100> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9b40>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/8BC68ABF-A736-4B7C-B082-7A17A0EEA60D.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262200> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9ae0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/F2B1DADE-CD85-4F64-91D1-3A4C84207B4E.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174265080> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a4020>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/E6358C25-2296-4441-AA6E-A015C409699E.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174260cc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9480>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/metadata.store-shm" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174263680> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9540>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427e7c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a6c60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/metadata.store-wal" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1742639c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aafe0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/.stage.nosync/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/8555B34F-46AA-4CB8-83CE-738E67A82A38.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174462980> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bc8c0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/A99ACC8B-E16E-4DD3-A20F-635DCF514E23.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261a40> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a98a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/969230F8-B32D-49C5-B31F-F512EFC36E70.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261fc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a8e20>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/41DCB49A-A693-43FC-A1B4-BA2EBD2E5B45.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170269c80> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a5c40>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/CB2102BC-10D5-47C8-A647-0B838A0197B3.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174079bc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9840>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/stores/test.sqlite-wal" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427b180> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa260>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/076BFC43-BD30-4684-914D-C0F64F29E39A.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174263200> - 1:0:1:0:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a97e0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/827A3965-33CB-4E86-9AC0-44177F3950DA.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1742623c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742ab1c0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/0449BB68-BF66-4104-A442-8C065AC087E2.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17007ad80> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9660>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/2391FEBB-8066-426E-9A81-55C906F8703F.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427b640> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aaaa0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/A25E48EB-88BF-4185-B3AD-1F5D5C115829.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261d40> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa620>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/baseline.gcmodel" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170268580> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa3e0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/2C4BD0A0-991C-47C6-9DE6-E03DA27C71A9.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170269780> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa320>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/D6183E45-7C5A-4E98-B6BD-7D275CBDE988.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174260000> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a96c0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/B38B652F-D4C8-4D0B-ACF0-1587147C98E6.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261900> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aace0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/2D09A7D4-99E6-4EF3-8D68-EA340512B8D3.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262cc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aaec0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1702686c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9600>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/.stage.nosync/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/2391FEBB-8066-426E-9A81-55C906F8703F.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174463140> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a95a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/3E7B6730-BD1E-49C3-9459-BD1B3E3E652F.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170269b80> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa020>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/CBD3B432-8DF5-43C9-8546-BBD0C20FB3E4.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174079c00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aab60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/0A1A594C-9C2E-4EFF-A5B7-0A6F17C0C137.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17026c900> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a94e0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/.stage.nosync/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/B1D0639C-4C5F-42CF-8864-3CC19DC1EDAA.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427f340> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a9780>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/A3697FCA-1ABA-471E-8D6C-F10022308DE0.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261c00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bc860>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/C759813C-9A63-4D32-97CF-1E5165067C36.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174079880> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa8c0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/stores/test.sqlite" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170268600> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa1a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/baseline.model" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174263a00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa920>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/272FCDFE-E1D2-4662-B157-8728AD3EFDB2.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170269700> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aa140>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/7FCD89BC-C846-49BF-A95A-5CFAB9448347.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262480> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a0a20>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/0E218E99-0962-46BD-AB22-7ABF8A9E936A.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170268900> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a6de0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/6B84E477-5DD1-430E-AF69-B765D3C028EB.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262800> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a08a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/1C6FE964-49C9-417E-AFFC-CEE28053E74D.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170462740> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a4da0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/080A1B89-749E-47A2-AF4F-A636C8A94454.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174263180> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a6f60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/8555B34F-46AA-4CB8-83CE-738E67A82A38.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427e640> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a0900>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/253BBE81-EA9F-4671-8969-F30D103D55FD.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170262ac0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a0960>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/staging.nosync" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170268480> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a71a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17427f140> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742ab700>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/36C921A5-4C1D-426E-81D8-F0FB58E54015.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262c40> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a7080>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/A45B5392-7058-47AB-BD24-6BFE75F44E08.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261ac0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aba60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/D184C67D-9CD9-4491-9106-3BC11496224D.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174079f40> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742ac900>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/27FCC3D4-E764-4FE2-ACFC-5C4E7AC290FD.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174262d40> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bfb00>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/9BD5A34F-70CC-46FB-921C-57B61AE9D9C0.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261dc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742aac20>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B.nosync" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170464b00> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a6420>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/43810FDD-2F3B-466F-AB6E-E942A1AEC398.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1742629c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a8d60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/9A26E6CE-F937-443E-AF55-2CF77A01ECD9.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174261f00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bfa40>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/receipt.0.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1742635c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a2f40>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/metadata.store" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1742638c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a22e0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/DCC947CE-E16F-461B-81AB-237C7062F630.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174260840> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a41a0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/CD617B67-1C1D-4DEB-906F-6C61A7BD51CE.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174079dc0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bfe60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/stores/test.sqlite-shm" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170462d80> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742ab040>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/current.nosync/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/stores" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x1702684c0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a3ae0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/myuser~18B3B992-1F5C-556D-9692-CCA3E72364E0/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/E424D9DB-095E-4249-80C5-690421CAC5CC.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170268380> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a0240>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/.baseline/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/staging.nosync/test.sqlite" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174263800> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:3";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a1fe0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/tempLogs.nosync/MyAppCloudStore/O0E9CJ8MXv4CrpcI30W5D66J__RwDzBqJB62ARBB~ag=/8555B34F-46AA-4CB8-83CE-738E67A82A38.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x17026ad40> - 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bfc20>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174460e00> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:2";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bfec0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/BF36B655-99AC-42DB-A12D-261312D3F504.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x174071040> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
    "<PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1742a3c60>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~test~test/CoreData/MyAppCloudStore/mobile~9DQOCDBD-08A2-22A9-B8C1-1UI67EB4DE8B/MyAppCloudStore/O0AACJ8OP24CrpcI30W5Q66J__RaDzBzJB134RBB~ag=/6A634643-DE1A-431D-9C13-18BB5CD53517.1.cdt" = "<PFUbiquityLocationStatus: 0x170269ec0> - 1:1:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:1";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem since days. Now it works on both: OSX <-> iOS.
    Running "startQuery" in a thread and adding notification "receiveUpdate:" made it working.

Here's my code:...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMetadataQuery * metadataQuery;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter;

...
//in Application launch:
 metadataQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[metadataQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray     arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K like '*.fcb'",     NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
[metadataQuery setPredicate:pred];
notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(endUpdate:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                           object:metadataQuery];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(recievedUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:metadataQuery];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [metadataQuery startQuery];
});

//then 
- (void)recievedUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Log file update
NSLog(@"[iCloud] An update has been pushed from iCloud with NSMetadataQuery");
// Get the updated files
[self updateICloudFiles];
}

-(void)endUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self updateICloudFiles];
}

-(void)updateICloudFiles{   
    [cloudFilenames removeAllObjects];
        for (NSMetadataItem *item in [metadataQuery results]) {
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSString *fileStatus;
        [url getResourceValue:&fileStatus     forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey error:nil];

        if ([fileStatus    isEqualToString:NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusDownloaded]) {
           // File will be updated soon
        }
        if ([fileStatus     isEqualToString:NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent]) {            
            if (![cloudFilenames containsObject:url])   {
                NSLog(@"success downloading: %@", [url lastPathComponent]);
                [cloudFilenames addObject:url];
            }
        } else if ([fileStatus     isEqualToString:NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusNotDownloaded]) {
            NSError *error;
            BOOL downloading = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]      startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:url error:&error];

        }

    }

    [cloudfilesTableView reloadData];
    [_ProgramStartOptions.lastFilesView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but it doesn't seem to work, endUpdate is not called... I added the observers in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Also I suddenly stopped receiving `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, don't know why, like usual no errors or anything in the console. I give up on iCloud, this is just to obscure and if you really have to write this code to get it working it's an horrendous api...